# Cloud Firestore - Flutter . Code stuck at '_primaryComplete.complete();'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner to Flutter and I started combining my application with Cloud Firestore today. I'm stuck at this for quite some time. Every time I press the IconButton the code would automatically jump to 'ticker.dart' at _primaryComplete.complete();.

I've also changed the rules in the Cloud Firestore to allow all inputs, but to no avail. Thanks for all your help.

[Code to save data to Cloud Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMiAZ.png)

[Code automatically jump here instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbeHs.png)

Tried to change the Cloud Firestore rules, but nothing worked. I'm not too sure what else I could do given my little knowledge.